# Using MATLAB GUIDE to list FTP files in a listbox

Tags: matlab, ftp, listbox, matlab-guide, listboxitem

I am having problems with listboxes in GUIDE. I want to display a list of files from an FTP server in a listbox. I make a matrix `A = dir(ftpobj)` after logging on to the server, then I make another matrix `A = A.name`, but this new matrix only has the FIRST file in the FTP directory. But weirdly, if I simply write `A.name`, all the files are listed. Is there a way to list ALL the files in the directory in matrix form? If so, how can I convert this matrix to a list of strings for the listbox?

Comment: Get all the data in a single cell array and then store it there.

Comment: `filelist = {A(:).name}';`